# How I can fix the below errors in my tex file to submit my paper to Arxiv?

Tags: pdftex, warnings, arxiv

I have tried to submit my paper to Arxiv-Cornel , I have generated my zip file ,The generated pdf from my tex file show no error , All my references are cited and all my equations are also appeared and cited as well , but when I tried to submit the paper to Arxiv-Cornel, I have got the below warning errors:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `G. LADAS' on page 1 undefined on input line 41.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 46--48


LaTeX Warning: Citation `M. Knopf' on page 1 undefined on input line 59.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `E. Camouzis' on page 1 undefined on input line 64.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq' on page 1 undefined on input line 64.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq' on page 1 undefined on input line 64.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Y.S. Huang' on page 1 undefined on input line 64.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq' on page 1 undefined on input line 64.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `F.J. Palladino' on page 1 undefined on input line 68.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `Eq' on page 1 undefined on input line 68.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `M. Knopf' on page 1 undefined on input line 68.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `Eq' on page 1 undefined on input line 70.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `G. LADAS' on page 1 undefined on input line 70.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `G. LADAS' on page 1 undefined on input line 70.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `E.A. Grove' on page 1 undefined on input line 70.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `M.R.S. Kulenovic' on page 1 undefined on input line 70
.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_1' on page 2 undefined on input line 79.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 84.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Y.KATO' on page 2 undefined on input line 89.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `R. Hirota' on page 2 undefined on input line 90.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 90.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_3' on page 2 undefined on input line 90.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `R. Hirota' on page 2 undefined on input line 90.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_3' on page 2 undefined on input line 90.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `V. Z. GRINES' on page 2 undefined on input line 90.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 94.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_4' on page 2 undefined on input line 99.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_5' on page 2 undefined on input line 99.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `M. Rogalski' on page 2 undefined on input line 99.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_5' on page 2 undefined on input line 99.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `E.A. Grove' on page 2 undefined on input line 99.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 99.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_6' on page 2 undefined on input line 106.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_4' on page 2 undefined on input line 111.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_4' on page 2 undefined on input line 111.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_6' on page 2 undefined on input line 111.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 111.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_4' on page 2 undefined on input line 111.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_4' on page 2 undefined on input line 115.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 115.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_5' on page 2 undefined on input line 115.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `E.A. Grove' on page 2 undefined on input line 115.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 115.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `ANNA CIMA' on page 2 undefined on input line 115.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 116.

[2]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_7' on page 3 undefined on input line 126.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Esmir Pilav' on page 3 undefined on input line 129.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_1' on page 3 undefined on input line 131.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `KULENOVIC' on page 3 undefined on input line 133.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_2' on page 3 undefined on input line 137.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_5' on page 3 undefined on input line 137.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq_7' on page 3 undefined on input line 137.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `V. Z. GRINES' on page 3 undefined on input line 137.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Peterson' on page 3 undefined on input line 137.

(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/ts1ntxtlf.fd)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 149--151

[3]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 160--162


! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.168

?
! Emergency stop.
```

Please what I can do to fix those errors in my tex file such that I work with Arxiv-style overleaflatex  ?

Comment: The warnings are normal as the references are undefined in the first run; the only issue is the error, you probably have a ``\\`` somewhere but without seeing the code it's impossible to say. What's on line 168?

Comment: @campa , yes I have used \\ in my tex to provide space between my section and paragraph , should I remove it ?

Comment: Almost surely, but again without seeing the code it's only a guess. Overleaf probably silently skips the error but the arXiv compiler is not so merciful.

Comment: Yes, there should never be any need to use ``\\`` in your running texts

Comment: the citation warnings will go if you run bibtex to generate the bibliography so you need to also submit your bib file or if the journal submission does not allow that submit the bbl file you generated locally.

Comment: @daleif , Thanks , I fixed the problem .The paper is already now submitted

Comment: i am facing the same problem as yours, how did you fix it?

Comment: Try to delete \\ from your tex